# .animate() works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9 but not IE10 (Jquery 1.8.3 and 1.9.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: FIXED: Thanks for everyone's help.

The problem turned out to be this orphan line in the CSS code:

- { transition: all 0.2s ease; }

Removing this line fixed the problem

Original Post:

I've just starting coding after a 10 year hiatus.  I am trying to get some code to work to animate a menu from the middle to top of the page.  It works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9 but is broken in IE10.  I've tried both JQuery 1.6.3 and 1.9.2 with no resolution.

Edit: The menu hover works fine in IE10.  By broken, I mean that the menu does not animate in IE10.  There are no javascript errors in the console in IE10.  The click does get captured fine in IE10, since window.location.href does change to appointments.html properly.

Snippet:

```
<header id="menubar" style="top: 496px; left: 80px; width: 1360px;">
  <ul id="surnav">
    <li class="menu-hover"> <a href=
      "index.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li id="appointments" class="menu-hover"> <a href=
      "#">Appointments</a> <img src="norwood_files/snav-arrow.png" width="10" height="5" />
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Emergencies</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if (document.URL.indexOf("index.html") >= 0) {
    $("#menubar").css("top", "496px");
    $(".menu-hover").on({
        click: function () {
            $("#menubar").animate({
                top: '50px'
            }, "easing:swing");
        },
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).children(".submenu, img").fadeIn(250);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).children(".submenu, img").fadeOut(250);
        }
    });

    $("#appointments").on({
        click: function () {
            $("#appointments-bkg").animate({
                top: '-14px'
            }, "easing:swing", function () {
                window.location.href = "appointments.html"
            });
        }
    });

    $("#financial").on({
        click: function () {
            $("#financial-bkg").animate({
                top: '-14px'
            }, "easing:swing", function () {
                window.location.href = "financial.html"
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does "broken" mean, and what are the JavaScript errors?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: there are no javascript errors.  the console has no errors

Comment: Does your HTML validate?  Is it possible that some invisible part of another element is covering/blocking the click?

Comment: Can you construct a jsFiddle that will demonstrate this problem?

Comment: Sparky, the HTML validates fine.  It is not possible that another element is blocking the click, since the window.location.href does get changed properly to appointments.html.  I will update the OP.

Comment: making fiddle now sparky.

Comment: BTW - put an `@` in front of my username if you want me to get the SO notification.

Comment: @Sparky Not able to replicate with fiddle, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/d2dft/1/

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.

The problem turned out to be this orphan line in the CSS code:

* { transition: all 0.2s ease; }

Removing this line fixed the problem

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below so that this can be "closed" out.  Don't forget to come back and "accept" your own answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try `if(window.location.href.match(/index\.html/i)` instead of `if(document.URL.indexOf("index.html") >= 0)` Other than that, considering that all other browsers are fine, I don't see why it's not working in IE10.

Comment: Actually, instead of doing a `string.match`, use `/regexp/.test(string)`. It is faster, and is exactly what you need.

I ^believe* recently, the `window.location` object was changed, as some code I wrote for a iframe-based XDM login broke due to `window.location.hash()` changing its behaviour (possibly in the newer versions of browsers)

Comment: thanks I will update the code with that.  I know, however, that the if statement is firing since the submenu fades work in IE10.  Could this be a bug in Jquery?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.

The problem turned out to be this orphan line in the CSS code:

* { transition: all 0.2s ease; }

Removing this line fixed the problem